# Monitoring PhD positions in CS

Tags: phd, application

Are there any ways of getting to know about new PhD positions in CS other then just looking trough university/research groups web sites? Maybe people from different branches can name some specialized mailing-lists where PhD positions announcements are quite usual. I am particularly looking out for computer systems, mainly dealing with cache problems, scheduling problems, multicore architectures, etc.

Here are a couple of websites that I found:

- [EuroSys — European Job Openings in Systems](http://www.eurosys.org/jobs/#doctoral),
- [PhDportal.com](https://www.phdportal.com/) (formerly [www.phdportal.eu](http://www.phdportal.eu)),
- [Research Grants | International Scholarships](http://scholarships4phd.blogspot.com/),
- [Scholarship Positions](http://scholarship-positions.com/),
- <del>http://youngbrigades.com/</del> (site has new, unrelated owner; verified on 26.12.2020).

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the field you want to study and have read some good papers, contact the authors and ask them what mailing lists are good for their field.

You might also state your motivation: they are generally good at knowing who has funding and may even be looking!

Comment: Maybe asking the author makes sense if you know him. if not, there are very slim chances of he replying back to our mail.
but just in case, you know someone, please do shoot a mail.. and get back to us..

Comment: you would be surprised - finding good students is often as hard as finding a funded phd.  also - other students may reply and be helpful, don't just email the profs!

Comment: That was a nice answer. However, that may not be the only way. If you know any websites, please shoot.

Comment: The biggest issue I can see with general websites that cover too many fields and you'll need to spend a lot of time to sift through them.

Comment: Sure. there is sure shot chance that the position is open :)

Answer (score 1):

Why this post is active again without any new answer or comment?

Anyway, in the past I found this page very useful, it has PhD/postdoc/faculty positions, CFPs so on and son on.
https://research.cs.wisc.edu/dbworld/browse.html