# Where to advertise PhD positions without paying a fee?

Tags: phd, application, computer-science, international-students, electrical-engineering

We have several opening in our group working in the field of computer science and electrical engineering (more specifically digital system design). We put an advertisement in our webpage and also another in the university portal. But we don't have applicants yet. I was looking for some websites to advertise the positions. I found that most of these websites (e.g. researchgate) ask for money. Do you know any website for advertising phd positions for free?

Comment: This might depend on your field. Please add that information to the question. Anyway, the costs for services that advertise such positions are usually negligible compared to the better visibility and resulting higher number of good applications. You should consider spending some money on this. There are also often some scientific mailing lists where sending job offers to is welcome and of course you can send an e-mail to your scientific network.

Comment: There are some *field-specific* websites, but they often charge a listing fee. If some money can be found to pay for the listing fee(s), and the site gets a wide exposure, it is absolutely worth advertising. You'll get more high quality applicants to choose from, and the cost of the advert is usually trivial in comparison to the cost of supporting a PhD student for 3+ years. If your positions are unpaid, it might be inappropriate or forbidden to advertise on job websites.

Comment: I frequently get announcements from different mailing lists of projects and departments. Send it to your colleagues and ask them to forward it to interested parties.

Comment: @Ronald I modified the question according to your suggestion.

Comment: If you add the exact fields of electrical engineering you might get more specific answers. For example, if it involves power systems / smart grids, then I would suggest to post on PowerGlobe mailing list.

Comment: @electrique I added the exact field

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Euraxess](http://ec.europa.eu/euraxess/index.cfm/jobs/index) may be an option. Its openings are quite heterogeneous (sciences and humanities). Despite the name, it is not restricted to European countries.

There are other free scholarship aggregators like [scholarship-positions.com](http://scholarship-positions.com/post-job-free-scholarship/). If you search academia.stackexchange you may be able to find [others](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7579/monitoring-phd-positions-in-cs).

Also, you may be able to find [reddit](https://www.reddit.com) channels associated to your area. At least in computer science it is not uncommon to see such openings posted there.

Another option is trying to locate a [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview) where other labs in your field post their openings.

Answer (score 11):

@ncasas has given a good answer. Two additional options are

1. Mailing lists - some disciplines/areas of expertise use these to advertise. For instance, I have frequently seen PhD and research positions advertised on the AIS mailing list, a mailing list used amongst information systems research, and on the an SEM mailing list, a mailing list used by researcher who use structural equation modelling in their research. If you can find either type of mailing list (i.e., related to your discipline, or your areas of expertise) then those would be good places to advertise.
2. Internal mailing lists. I occasionally hear about positions from my supervisor or others in the school who receive emails from others who ask them to advertise positions within the school. If you have contacts in good universities who may have graduating students who might be interested in your positions, then you could probably pursue this option.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

1. Social media - like twitter or specific groups on facebook
2. Blogs - if there are some scientific blogs about your discipline/area you could write an email to an author and ask him/her if he/she could post this advertisement